# Python calculating power vs. factorial

Tags: python, largenumber

I am in university at the moment and one of my subjects is discrete maths.
From discrete maths I know that n! > 2^n for n > 3. I know python can calculate 20,000!, I have done it on my computer, granted it takes a few seconds. But it cannot calculate 2 to the power of something as little as 1,500, which is certainly smaller. Any ideas why?

Comment: You can calculate 2^(20000) in a blink with python.

Comment: In python: `2**1500`

Comment: *discrete* mathematics and *discreet* mathematics are different things ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to only be a problem in the math.pow function provided by the C standard. It appears to fail because `math.pow` uses floats, but `**` uses `long`. `math.pow(2, 1023)` will work, `math.pow(2, 1024)` will fail.

```
In [1]: 2**1500
Out[1]: 35074662110434038747627587960280857993524015880330828824075798024790963850563322203657080886584969261653150406795437517399294548941469959754171038918004700847889956485329097264486802711583462946536682184340138629451355458264946342525383619389314960644665052551751442335509249173361130355796109709885580674313954210217657847432626760733004753275317192133674703563372783297041993227052663333668509952000175053355529058880434182538386715523683713208549376L

In [2]: from math import pow

In [3]: pow(2, 1500)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-fa67a1c786b4> in <module>()
----> 1 pow(2, 1500)

OverflowError: math range error
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the ** operator for python.